# How to transfer tokens from within a contract?

Tags: tokens, transfer

I went through the tutorial adding inline actions to external contracts. I understood most of it but it didnt work with eosio.token contract. I have my contract. From that contract I want to create an action that is able to call the transfer action from the eosio.token contract. How do I do that? Ive googled it but didn't find an answer that works for me.

```
   [[eosio::action]]
void transfer(name user, name reciever,asset quant, std::string memo){
    eosio.token::transfer_action transfer("eosio.token"_n, {get_self(), "active"_n});
    transfer.send(user,reciever,quant,memo);
}
```

I tried it like this but it didn't work.

Comment: are you getting the "transaction declares authority <user>, but does not have signatures for it" too?